# When are (System)Verilog parameters calculated?

Tags: parameters, verilog, system-verilog

Say I define

`module Foo
#(parameter a = 8, parameter b= $clog2(a)) ...`

and then instantiate

`Foo #(.a(16)) bar (...)`

When is default parameter b calculated?   Based on the actual value of a or the default value of a?  Does instance bar see b=3 or b=4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always the *final* value.

Section **23.10 Overriding module parameters** in the [1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) describes the elaboration process that the compiler goes through to set parameter values. Basically, the compiler can figure out the the dependencies between parameter values because of restrictions it places on the allowable expressions you can make to a parameter value.

> **23.10.3 Parameter dependence**
>
> A parameter (for example, memory_size) can be defined with an expression  containing another parameter (for example, word_size). However, overriding a parameter, whether by a defparam statement or in a module instantiation statement, effectively replaces the parameter definition with the new expression.  Because memory_size depends on the value of word_size, a modification of word_size changes the value of memory_size. For example, in the following parameter declaration, an update of word_size, whether by defparam statement or in an instantiation statement for the module that defined these
>   parameters, automatically updates memory_size. If memory_size is updated due to either a defparam or an instantiation statement, then it will take on that value, regardless of the value of word_size.
>   
>   `parameter
>       word_size = 32,
>       memory_size = word_size * 4096;`

Comment: Is it not obviously from this answer or the linked spec what the direct answer to the question is.   Can you point out the relevant excerpt?   Bottom line, is the answer b=3 or b=4 and why according to the LRM?

Comment: Specifically look at subsection 23.10.3 Parameter dependence and the example using `word_size`

Comment: I took the liberty of quoting the relevant section.